# Where do browsers keep temporary files?

Tags: firefox, chromium

How do I get in to my Temp Internet files?

In running Ubuntu 11.10 on an HP Laptop
I normally use Chromium but still have Fire Fox installed

Comment: Duplicate question w/ answer here: http://superuser.com/questions/223774/google-chrome-and-firefox-cache-in-ubuntu

Comment: You chromium-browser cache should be here by default: 
~/.cache/chromium/Default/Cache

Answer (score 7):

Chromium is kept under `~/.cache/chromium/Default/Cache`.

Firefox is kept under `~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/Cache`.

You can navigate to those using Nautilus and selecting *View* > *Show Hidden Files* (or press <kbd>crtl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> on a Nautilus window).

For Ubuntu 11: Make sure to be in the "Home" folder first then continue with the above folder navigation.

Comment: This answer is apparently no longer correct at least for Firefox 63.0 on Ubuntu 18.10; there's no Cache folder at the described location. ~/.cache/mozilla/firefox/*.default/cache2/entries/ appears to be the correct location.

Answer (score 0):

To mark a file or directory as hidden on Linux/Unix, make sure its name begins with a "dot."

```
cd ~
mkdir .hidden_directory
```

Knowing this, open a shell.

```
ls -a
```

See the ~/.cache and ~/.mozilla directories?

```
cd .cache
ls
```

Two caches... one for Chrome/Chromium and one for Mozilla Firefox. The Firefox cache is **~/.mozilla/firefox/$random_profile_id.default/Cache**
You could also do this with a graphical file manager, but tell it to show hidden files.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 18.04.2, 
Chromium cache is located here:

```
~/snap/chromium/common/.cache/chromium/Default/Cache
```

Opera Cache:

```
~/snap/opera/common/.cache/opera/Cache
```

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox, if you choose to "open file with" when you download (for example, a .deb package).  The file gets stored in: `/tmp/mozilla_YourUsername0/`

And following the example of choosing to open a .deb package with 'software installer' it appears the file also gets copied to `/tmp/gnome-software-*/`

command for searching:

```
$ find /directory/to/search -name yourFileName.extension
```