# Where do browsers save cookies and data?

Tags: firefox, chromium

What is the default location for the Firefox or Chromium web browser to store data?

Also, where are the temporary data and cookies, along with user profiles, stored?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Temp Internet files](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88325/temp-internet-files)

Comment: but where are the cookies and all my data stored?

Comment: Even if web browser don't follow it nowadays, I think it's good to point out that the [XDG Base Directory Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) should be the answer to this question.

Answer (score 12):

Chromium cache is kept under `~/.cache/chromium/Default/Cache`.

Firefox cache is kept under `~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/Cache`.

You can navigate to those using Nautilus and selecting *View* > *Show Hidden Files* (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> on a nautilus window).

The user's profile for Firefox is kept under `~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/`. It contains cache, addons, user settings, etc.

The user's profile for Chromium is kept under `~/.cache/chromium/Default`, also contains all the files related to the user: cache, settings, addons, etc.

Comment: hm.. I have no Cache folder in there, but I know there is a cookie, and I want to modify it.

Answer (score 3):

I think this information about the location of cookies is out of date. In Ubuntu 16.04 using Mozilla 50.1.0 the cookies are not stored in -

```
~/.mozilla/firefox/xxxxxxx.default/Cache
```

In fact this Cache folder does not exist. The cookies are stored in an SQLite database file called cookies.sqlite. So the correct path name is -

```
~/.mozilla/firefox/xxxxxx.default/cookies.sqlite
```

Just to make it a bit more complicated you have to use an SQLite database browser to look at them. I hope this helps.

Comment: If you post it like this you do need to explain xxxxx is NOT what you need to type but needs to be change to something else. Plus  behind the ".default"  is another set of characters ;)

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can browse through your `/home/$your-username` folder, in mine I have it as `/home/home`

Generally speaking, people use `~/` as a shortcut for `/home/$your-username`

so for Mozilla it will be under `~/.mozilla`.

for Chromium it will be under `~/.cache/chromium`.

you can use nautilus file manager to browse through those directories.

Comment: `/home/home`? That's interesting...