# Where does "open with" go

Tags: internet, files, storage

When I download a file from the Internet I can choose "open with" or "save as". When i choose "open with", does it get saved somewhere on the disk? Or is it gone when I close the file? Like totally gone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/88325/where-do-browsers-keep-temporary-files

Comment: It depends, but in general it should be in /tmp, and then gets deleted depending on many parameters (application, browser, tmpfs on RAM, and such)

Comment: Maybe not a duplicate, but an answer in itself... "Open With..." creates a temp file, which then [see @Michal 's comment] ... Chain of events!

Comment: 'Save as' does save the file to disk, and 'open with' saves the file to RAM memory, so that file can be opened/used by specified software, but not by user (for future reference). 'Open with' makes that file a temporary file, not available to the user, and totally lost after reboot or RAM memory cleanup. 'Open with' works in all situations, 'open with' works in most situations, with a couple exceptions, like the magnet links. You can't save a magnet link to disk, but you an open it with (specific) software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox will create a temp folder following the pattern

```
/tmp/mozilla_${USERNAME}${INDEX}
```

where `${USERNAME}` of course represents your user name and `${INDEX}` an index starting at 0 to avoid conflicts between multiple running instances. So for me this directory could e.g. be called

```
/tmp/mozilla_bytecommander0
```

Inside this directory, it will save the files downloaded to directly <kbd>Open with...</kbd> an application with their default name, same as if you selected <kbd>Save file....</kbd>.

These temporarily stored files will stay in this location on your hard disk at most until you quit Firefox. Then it should clean this directory. Not sure of this clean up can also be triggered by other events before Firefox exits, I could not observe any yet.